# mockito NullPointerException

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit4

Hi I have the following test and I cannot make it work, its giving `NullPointerException`:

Method to test :

```
private ResponseEntity getDefaultCart(HttpEntity<String> request, String zoomQuery) {
    LOG.info("Get user's default cart with zoom query" + zoomQuery);
    String defaultCartUrl = cortexApiUrl + Constants.CARTS + scope + Constants.DEFAULT + Constants.ZOOM + zoomQuery;
    return baseRepository.getCall(defaultCartUrl, request);
}
```

Junit of this method:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateCart() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    cortexRepository= new CortexRepositoryImpl("https://abc.juy", "ocean", baseRepositoryImpl);
    Mockito.when(baseRepositoryImpl.createRequestHeaders("guestId")).thenReturn(httpHeaders);
    JSONObject orderDetails = createCortexCreateOrderObject("cortexCreateOrderResponse.json");
    ResponseEntity<JSONObject> entity=new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(orderDetails,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);
    Mockito.when(baseRepositoryImpl.getCall("http://www.abc.hyh", request)).thenReturn(entity);
    cortexRepository.updateCart(updateCartRequest);
}
```

Method `getDefaultCart` is calling from `updateCart` method.The object `orderDetails` is filling correctly.

NUllPointer is giving on line : `baseRepository.getCall(defaultCartUrl, request)`.

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

I think that the instance of `BaseRepositoryImpl` being used when you call `baseRepository.getCall(defaultCartUrl, request);` is not the same instance being passed to `new CortexRepositoryImpl("https://abc.juy", "ocean", baseRepositoryImpl);`.

So make sure that you are not creating a new instance of it in `CortexRepositoryImpl` and are in fact using the object passed into the constructor.

I can't be sure without the source of `CortexRepositoryImpl` but this seems like the most likely issue.